# Искра и искрА

Tags: фонетика

Когда речь идет об огне, например, костра, то всегда говорят "Искра", но если об искре в моторе, то чаще можно услышать "искрА". Что это: профессиональный жаргон или все-таки безграмотность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верно: **и**скра. Искр**а** - профессиональный жаргон

Comment: Как-то непонятно. Одинаково же.

Comment: Нет, не одинаково. Верно с ударением на И (выделено),а если ударение падает на А (искрА)- это профессиональный жаргон.

Comment: Из песни политзаключённых, просвящённой товарищу Сталину: "Вы там (в Туруханском крае) из Искры раздували пламя - Спасибо Вам: я греюсь у костра". У Высоцкого этого вопроса не стояло.

Answer (score 2):

Есть торЕц, а у токарей он тОрец, так же, как и у шахтёров дОбыча, а не добЫча.

Answer (score 0):

А меня, помнится, учили,что правильно как раз искрА.

Comment: Плохо Вас учили

Comment: В связи с этим можно спросить : когда говорят **и**скристый, а когда искр**и**стый?

Comment: А вот это как раз их другой серии. **И**скристый - допутимый вариант, обычно поэтический.

Answer (score 0):

В отношении "жаргона" дело обстоит, думаю, следующим образом. 
Наличие тока, проверяемого с помощью известного метода - искрА.
Нормативными словарями не фиксируется, но именно в таком значении употребляется при разговоре об автомобилях, иначе Вас просто не поймут. Во всех остальных, будь то профессиональное или общее значение - искра.

Answer (score 0):

Ударение на И — Искра, Искры (в розетке, в/из глаз). В профессиональном сленге: на А — искрА (в автомеханике, электрике).